# Showing a map is a bounded linear operator.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, normed-spaces

Show that the map

A : (C[0,1],∥·∥∞) → R, Ax = x(0), ∀x ∈ C[0,1]

is a bounded linear operator.

I know one has to show the map is continuous but I'm not sure how to go about proving it in this case. Any help would and I will be very grateful.

There is another part to the question asking to find its operator norm.

Comment: Hint for showing continuity: probably, your familiar with the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity from calculus. You can use that here, too.

Comment: Steps for solving this exercise could be: 1. show that $A$ is linear, 2. compute the operator norm, 3. if the norm is finite conclude that $A$ is continous.

Comment: @hagen thanks thats a big help.